# `matplotlib`: Drawing a polygon with "vertex markers". PatchCollections, path_effects, or something else?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I will be drawing a large number of irregular polygons as `patches` (using [`PathCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html), also see [`collections` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html)), after first creating their [`path`s](http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html).

I know how to change things like fill colour, edge colour, transparency, and so on, for the edges of the polygons. I'd also like to mark the vertices somehow, with smaller, filled circles perhaps?

This is where I am uncertain how to proceed. Here are the options I have identified, and the problems with them:

1. I can draw the vertices using `path`s as well (for example, using circle paths with the right style, placed at the right location. Then, I can convert these to a `patch`es as well. So, the `PatchCollection` in the end will be composed of the polygon edge patches, and polygon vertex patches. The only issue with this idea is that there seems to be some sort of a disconnect perhaps between the idea that the two patches are "related", so I am not sure if it's the right way to do it.
2. I can make a `PatchCollection` for each polygon (let's say I call them `MyPolygonPatchCollection` which contains both the edge path patches, and the vertex patches. Then, I make a `PathCollection` of `MyPolygonPatchCollection`objects. I don't think that `PathCollection`s can have other `PatchCollection`s as subelements though, [as far as I understand the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection)?
3. I could use `path_effect`s somehow, but how to accomplish this is pretty opaque to me, even after having a look at the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/patheffects_guide.html?highlight=patheffects#module-matplotlib.patheffects).
4. I could use `LineCollection` and `Line2D` objects to draw every edge (along with the marker style I want) instead of `pathch`es defined from custom `path`s? I don't like this idea much, because I was looking forward to just having a tidy box representing my polygons.

Can you advise?

Comment: If you have all of the polygon coordinate data ahead of time (and if I understand the question correctly), what about just using a `scatter` plot of all the points on top of the polygons?

Comment: @chdorr That's about the same as option 1), I think, where I just draw a bunch of circle paths everywhere. So, I guess I am wondering if its possible to somehow organize associated paths.

Comment: you don't have to draw circle paths; `scatter` will produce points, which you can style as you please: see [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html) demo. And as far as organizing them goes, I don't see the issue: the polygon xy data is the same as your intended point data, correct?

Comment: @chdorr I guess so. I mean, the `scatter` function probably just uses `CirclePath`s to do what it does though. So, instead of using `scatter`, which doesn't give me an object I can control as easily as `path`s, I might as well use `CirclePath`?